# Written numbers are fewer than the ones read from a file

Tags: c, arrays, qsort

So, I have this program which reads two columns of integers from a file and stores them in an 2d array and then shorts the array according to the first column. Those numbers can appear multiple times. Thats why I need another that stores the numbers individually. The numbers might exist on the left and on the right column. The problem is that the numbers that are stored on that array are fewer than the ones on the file (it prints 6110 numbers while the individual numbers are 7115)

The file looks like this:

```
1381    5026
1381    5323
1381    6347
1383    1384
1383    1389
1383    2963
1383    4179
1384    56
1384    762
1384    1049
1384    1154
```

The code looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int mapdoublesize(int** map,int nodes){
    int* new_array=malloc(nodes*2*sizeof(int));
    if(new_array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<nodes;i++){
        new_array[i]=(*map)[i];
    }
    nodes*=2;
    free(*map);
    *map=new_array;
    return nodes;
}

typedef struct {
    int start;
    int end;   
} path;

int cmp(const void *a,const void *b){
    int l=((path*)a)->start;
    int r=((path*)b)->start;

    if(l>r)
        return 1;
    if(l<r)
        return -1;
    if(l==r)
        return 0;
}

int doublesize(path** array,int n){
    path* new_array=malloc(n*2*sizeof(path));
    if(new_array==NULL){
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        new_array[i]=(*array)[i];
    }
    free(*array);
    *array=new_array;
    n*=2;
    return n;

}


int main()
{
    int maxsize=10;
    int test;
    path* array=malloc(maxsize*sizeof(path));
    if(array==NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }


    FILE* fd=fopen("Test.txt","r");
    if(fd==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        abort();
    }
    char buff[200];
    int counter=0;

    char c;
while(fgets(buff,200,fd)) {

        c=buff[0];
        if(c=='#') {
            continue;
        }
    sscanf(buff,"%d%d",&array[counter].start,&array[counter].end);
        counter++;
        if(counter==maxsize){
           maxsize=doublesize(&array,maxsize); 
    }

    }
    maxsize=counter;
    qsort(&array[0],maxsize,sizeof(path),cmp);


    counter = 0;
int nodes = 10;
int *map = malloc(nodes * sizeof(int));
if (map == NULL) {
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
}   
int i;
for(i=0;i<maxsize;i++){
    if(map[counter-1]==array[i].start)
        continue;
        map[counter]=array[i].start;
        counter++;
        if(counter==nodes){
          nodes=mapdoublesize(&map,nodes);
        }
}
int j;
for(i=0;i<maxsize;i++){
    for(j=0;j<counter;j++){
        if(map[j]==array[i].end);
            break;
    }
    if(j!=counter)
        continue;
    map[counter]=array[i].end;
    counter++;
    if(counter==nodes)
        nodes=mapdoublesize(&map,nodes);
}

nodes=counter;
for(i=0;i<nodes;i++){
    printf("%d\n",map[i]);
}
printf("%d\n",nodes);   
    fclose(fd);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try step-by-step debugging?

Comment: Before that, try formatting it for readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a potential problem in this loop, line 112 of your code, the `if` clause has a semicolon, rendering it useless:

```
for(i=0; i<maxsize; i++){
    for(j=0; j<counter; j++){
        if(map[j]==array[i].end); // <-- this if has a semicolon rendering the if useless
            break;
    }
    if(j != counter)
        continue;
    map[counter]=array[i].end;
    counter++;
    if(counter==nodes)
        nodes=mapdoublesize(&map,nodes);
}
```

Thought it might not be the only problem. After this correction, your code is not counting or storing repeated numbers.

Comment: Adding my two cents: modern compilers are pretty good at detecting this; in Visual Studio 2019 I get: `';': empty controlled statement found; is this the intent?`. Adding `-Wall` in compiler options is always a good idea

Comment: That's at least five cents :)